# Xcode 14 forces me into Bitcode for Unity builds. Why?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, bitcode

Since I updated Xcode to version 14, it requires that all pods included in my Unity project have been built for Bitcode. This is especially strange since Xcode has *deprecated* Bitcode now. Can anyone explain why it requires something that it did not require before, if this feature is not recommended anymore? This does not make any sense to me.

I would also appreciate any link to a Unity build script that sets the Bitcode flag automatically on all pods. Thanks.

Comment: Your last phrase is off-topic as asking for a tool/book/library/other external resource (see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). I would rephrase this to e.g. "(How) Can you automatically set the Bitcode flag on all pods via script during a build process?"

Comment: Unity no longer set that flag, if you still see ENABLE_BITCODE in your project's plist, upgrade the Unity.

Comment: I am on the latest 2021 build of Unity.